# Is there any callback function on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following link:

```
<a  href="#shippingaddress" onclick="return validateBillingAddress(document.addressInput,'ADDR_CONTINUE_ACTION',event);" >
```

**EDIT**
**i am using multi page approach to show different section(divs) as a page**
in that validate function I am validating the form and if everything is ok then displaying a hidden `<div>` and after the `<div>` is visible `<spans>` are getting applied by jquery mobile framework, untill and unless that div is hidden there is no `span,` but as that div become visible jquery mobile gets applied on it and appended some spans..i need to access this spans :

```
<span>blah</span>
```

So I want to change the text of this `<span>` after the `click` event, because the `<span>` is displayed after the `click` event.

So is there any way to do this?

Comment: While appending itself you can change the content right?

Comment: actually..that spans are getting applied by jquery mobile framework, untill and unless that div is hidden there is no span, but as that div become visible jquery mobile gets applied on it and appended some spans..i need to access this spans

Comment: which jQuery mobile function adds that span? Is the span automatically added after a $.mobile.changePage() or what?

Answer (score 1):

In your validate function you can do this:

```
 <div id="someDiv" style="display:none">
     <span id="someSpan"></span>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function validateBillingAddress() {
         var valid = true;
         ... // do whatever you need to validate your input here and update valid variable

         if (valid) {
             $('#someDiv').show();  
             // if the validation is succesful invoke some function in the framework here
             $.ajax({
                 ...
                 success: function() {
                     //append the span to the div here
                     $(#someDiv').append('The span HTML content');
                 },
                 ...
             });                

         }
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: instead of "there is no span in the div when it is invisible", you can just put a span inside the hidden div (the span won't show too). After that your jQuery mobile can update that span easily rite?

Comment: If you insist on having no span inside the div, your jQuery mobile framework can call this function `$('#someDiv').append("Put your span HTML here");` to append that span element to the div element. Of course, you can only do this after calling `$('#someDiv').show();`. Otherwise, the user cannot see your update =)

Comment: yes this is the case..it's gets appended only when that validate function call is over and div get's displayed..at this point i want some callback which can tell me now you have that span and you can access that

Comment: I have no idea how your jQuery framework looks like. I take an Ajax call as an example in my answer. You invoke some function in your jQuery framework and on success return of the function, you append the span element to the div element. That success function will tell you that the span element is here.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use inline javascript...

```
$("#validate").click(function(){
    // validate billing address
});

<a id="validate">Validate</a>
```

To create a span and attach a listener to it, then append to the div:

```
$("<span />").click(function(){
    $(this).text("New Text");
}).appendTo("#divToShow");
```

Edit:

Since you haven't provided much information, the only thing I can help you out is:

1- To access all spans within the div, you do:

```
$("#myDivId span")
```

2- To access only spans that are direct children of the div, you do:

```
$("#myDivId > span")
```

3- To access only the last span within the div, you do:

```
$("#myDivId span:last")
```

More than that, only if you provide some actual generated code

Comment: Still, my answer remains, unless you have no control over the appended spans, which you haven't specified. In this case, please give some more code.

Comment: yes i have no control over spans..once they comes in picture at that time i have to access that

Comment: Please clarify one more thing to me: do you have to change the text as soon as it shows, or when the user clicks on the span?

Comment: thing is that span .. gets appended only when that validate function call is over and div get's displayed..at this point i want some callback which can tell me now you have that span and you can access that

Answer (score 0):

You could actually embed the validateBillingAddress into another function, containing the "callback" line as well

```
function doValidate( event ) {
  validateBillingAddress(document.addressInput,'ADDR_CONTINUE_ACTION',event);
  $('#spanElement').text( 'new text' );
}
```

And then

```
<a onclick="return doValidate( event );" >
```

Would be even better if you avoided using the onclick property in favor of a non-invasive event handling like

```
$('#aElement').click( function( e ) {
  doValidate( e );
});
```